# How do I create a table of a 28 hour clock, by 1 minute intervals?

Tags: r, time, sequence, hour, minute

I am not very familiar with using loops. I am trying to create a table like this:
00:00
00:01
00:02
...
27:58
27:59
28:00

It is for data that runs into the next day, but is still considered part of the original day.

I tried this:

```
hh<-c(seq('00','28',1))  
mm<-c(seq('01','60',1))

for (i in (1:29)) {
  int<-paste(hh[i],":",mm)
}
View(int)
```

but it only does the pastes minutes 1 through 60 onto hour 28:
[only the 28th hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eszK.png)

I hope this is simpler than I am making it out to be, I don't know how to use the sapply or lapply to do this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I seem to be getting somewhere. I tried:
```
int<-c(sapply(hh, paste, mm))
View(int)
```
but I am missing the ":" in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the help of `outer` :

```
times <- c(t(outer(sprintf('%02d', 0:27),sprintf('%02d', 0:59),paste,sep = ":")))
#add the last time manually
times <- c(times, '28:00')

head(times, 8)  
#[1] "00:00" "00:01" "00:02" "00:03" "00:04" "00:05" "00:06" "00:07"
tail(times, 8)  
#[1] "27:53" "27:54" "27:55" "27:56" "27:57" "27:58" "27:59" "28:00"
```

`sprintf` appends 0 to a single digit number and we `paste` every hour (0 to 27) to every minute (0 to 59).

Comment: would also `gsub(' ', '0', times)` or something since `For numbers, pad to the field width with leading zeros. For characters, this zero-pads on some platforms and is ignored on others.`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as well:

```
hh<-c(seq('00','28',1))
mm<-c(seq('00','59',1))

library(stringr)
hh<-str_pad(hh, 2,pad="0")
mm<-str_pad(mm, 2,pad="0")

times<-c(sapply(hh, paste, sep=":",mm))
View(times)
```